# object reference is required for the non-static field

Tags: c#

What am I doing wrong here?

```
return listBoxKeywords.Items[rnd.Next(0, listBoxKeywords.Items.Count)].ToString();
```

I get the following error:

Error   1   An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property

Comment: please post a larger code snippet including the declaration of the variables that are listed on that line.

Comment: Doing too much in one line ... and I don't think it's that line that is not compiling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error means that the function returning the random item is static.

Either remove the `static` keyword from the method declaration (and thus make it part of the existing instance), or pass the list box as parameter to the function when calling it.

Comment: I think that the error actually saying that it is calling a non static property or method as if it were static.  Which requires an instance of an object.

Comment: It could be the `rnd` as well but it's probably the list.

Comment: @stefan: that is what the Shadow is saying too. You can solve it in 2 ways.

Comment: I think shadow is saying the opposite.  The problem is not that the method IS static, the error is that it is NOT static.

Comment: @StefanH no. The error says "An object reference is required for the **non-static field**" - now let's assume that field is `listBoxKeywords`. It means that the field is not static, thus "bound" to some instance. Static function is not bound to any instance, thus throwing such error. Maybe we're talking about the same thing from two different angles, as Henk mentioned..

Comment: @Henk good point about possible culprit being `rnd`, I missed that - but the principal is the same. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard  That makes complete sense now!  I was not viewing the listBoxKeywords as being the static field that the error was referring to, but rather that they were trying to call a method that requires an object on a class, rather than an object.  Thank you for the clarification!